# How to solve given differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$ 4x^{3}y''(x)+6.y'(x^{2})-2x^{2}y'(x)-3y(x^{2})+2.xy(x)=\dfrac{1}{2(1-x^{2})} $$
I have tried to express $y$ as a power series and then expanding the right side to binomial coefficients but I'm getting stuck there, I cant invert it to standard functions.

Comment: Even if we dismiss $y(x^2)$ as a typo, this looks far too complicated to be solvable.

Comment: In this case, the notation of derivative with apostrophe is ambiguous. Do you mean $\quad y'(x^2)=\left(\frac{dy(X)}{dX}\right)_{X=x^2}\quad $ or $\quad y'(x^2)=\frac{dy(x^2)}{dx}$ ? They are different. $\quad $ For example with $y(x)=\sin(x)\quad $ we have $\quad \left(\frac{d\sin(X)}{dX}\right)_{X=x^2}=\cos(X)=\cos(x^2)\quad $ and $\quad \frac{d\sin(x^2)}{dx}=2x\cos(x^2)$.

Comment: it's the second one @JJacquelin

Comment: $$\Big(4x^{3}y''(x)-2x^{2}y'(x)+2.xy(x)\Big)+\Big(\dfrac{3}{x}.y'(x^{2})2x-3y(x^{2})\Big)=\dfrac{1}{2(1-x^{2})}$$
$$(2x)\Big(2x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)\Big)+\dfrac{3}{x}\Big((y(x^{2}))'-xy(x^{2})\Big)=\dfrac{1}{2(1-x^{2})}$$
$$(2x)\Big(2x^2y''(x)-xy'(x)+y(x)\Big)+\dfrac{3}{x}e^{\frac12x^2}\Big(e^{-\frac12x^2}y(x^{2})\Big)'=\dfrac{1}{2(1-x^{2})}$$

Comment: Where did this monster come from? I wonder what kind of problem led to this equation. (Note, it would be more correct to call this "functional-differential equation")